# Can "No Thru Traffic" signs be enforced in New Hampshire

Tags: united-states, traffic, new-hampshire

I was reading an article that said in California "No Thru Traffic" signs cannot legally be enforced (aside from the temporary ones used for construction work). I searched Google but cannot find whether or not this is also true for New Hampshire. Does anyone here know whether it is also true in NH, or at least where I could find the laws on this issue?